# How to upload and trim video by time limit flutter

Tags: flutter

Is possible in flutter make video upload and user can make trim video with maximum time limit then upload video like instagram ?

How to make like that system ?

1. User pick video
2. User trim video with maximum time limit
3. Upload video

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Is it cookie cutter easy? No.

Comment: Is ffmpeg possible do that ?

Comment: That could be part of the equation, yes.

Comment: can we trim video like instagram and whatsapp frame by frame in flutter?